# Issues with lost / damaged GRUB - cant rebuild. Need help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Im looking for some assistance, as somehow i managed to kill my GRUB settings, and now i boot into the rescue mode.

My system is not the best layed out, as I have Win 8.1 on a UEFI loader, and when i installed Ubuntu, for some unkown reason i had set the bios to go Legacy. It all installed fine, I even installed Kali besides Ubuntu and it was all fine. (I did apparently set GRUB to boot from the Kali install some how).

So fast forward to me shrinking the NTFS volume in win 8, and creating a fat32 partition with the plan to be able to pass data between the OS's.

Booting back into Legacy, Grub returns the error "unkown filesystem". I get the rescue mode. Which luckily lets me add in the following:

```
set root=(hd0,6)
set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

So i can get to my grub boot loader.
But when i do

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

the update grub works fine, but the grub install spits out an error stating "This GPT partition label contains no BIOS boot partition. embedding wont be possible.
then errors out saying it will not proceed with blocklists.

This happens on both the Kali install and the Ubuntu install.

Im guessing one way is to blow away the Kali install, and put a new distro on there, and having it install grub. But im afraid if it goes wrong, ive lost the only way i can get back into my existing Ubuntu distro.

ive also tried boot-repair which fails out with normal fix as well as custom setting telling it to not use the standard EFI file.

Still i get no where.

I appreciate any help i can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a perfect fix, I was able to shrink my Windows volume (for the last time) to give me 30Gb free. Then a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onto that free space. Somehow the installation doesnt care about how its set up and just gets the job done. The simple step afterwards was just to fix up the boot preferences in the new ubuntu install so i can tell the difference between the new partition and the old partition.

Whle im sure this is not what anyone would consider a proper fix, grub is now behaving correctly. And I have a spare install of Ubuntu on the system for whatever i can figure out to do with it.

Ironically, i now have 2 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, a Kali Linux, and a Windows 8.1 on this poor little laptop.

If anyone has a better fix, id love to know it. And I hope this fix I used can help someone else if they have the same issue.